# Idioms similar to "dig your own grave"

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-requests, idioms

I'm looking for an idiom or phrase similar to "dig your own grave"

It's for this scenario:

Person 1 made a comment and is now attempting to explain it/talk themselves out of an awkward situation, but they are just making it worse.

Person 2 tells them ***"stop, you're digging your own grave"***

I need something better than "digging your own grave" because it doesn't flow with the rest of the scenario. It's not snappy/quick enough.

Could **"quit while you're ahead"** work? It sounds good but based on the meaning of it I'm not sure it fits properly.

I hope someone can help - I also hope my question makes sense, I have no idea it's half 6 in the morning and I haven't slept yet so brain is running a little slower than normal :P

CJ x

Comment: Related: [Equivalent English phrase for “don't roll around where you've fallen”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/435385/142322). Is your question covered by the answers there?

Comment: I've looked there and haven't found anything that fits what I'm looking for, but thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome. It's customary on EL&U to reference closely-related questions and explain why the other question or its answers weren't helpful (you can [edit] that information into your question directly). This helps the community to understand more precisely what you're looking for.

Comment: Given that it is such a well known idea, can you just abbreviate it, as people often do, to 'stop digging...'?

Comment: Related and possible duplicate: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/319758

Comment: So, one criterion is an idiom that doesn't consist of more than four words? Otherwise, please clarify what you mean by "snappy."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I offer two idioms for your consideration: **quit while [one is] behind** and **cut [one's] losses**.

But first, let's look at the more traditional phrase "quit while [one is] ahead." Christine Ammer, *The American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms*, second edition (2013) has this entry for that phrase:

> **quit while one's ahead** Don't try to improve on something that is already accomplished, as in Those drapes we hung are even enough—let's quit while we're ahead. This idiom also implies that further action runs the risk of spoiling something. Also see LEAVE WELL ENOUGH ALONE.

According to Charles Doyle, Wolfgang Mieder & Fred Shapiro, *The [Yale] Dictionary of Modern Proverbs* (2012), the expression "quit while you're ahead" goes back only to 1919:

> **Quit while you're ahead**
>
> 1919 Charles E. Van Loan, *Score by Innings* (New York: George H. Doran) 245: "'That's right!' growls Sam Horgan, who was down on the floor with the dice. 'Quit while you're ahead, you cheap skates!'"

Within fifty years, however, people had begun occasionally using a variation on this expression that comes much closer to the sense that the posted question requires: **quit while [one is] behind**, meaning to stop making things worse by continuing to pursue a losing or failing course of action.

For example, from Ohio AFL-CIO, [*News and Views*](https://books.google.com/books?id=oOpaAAAAYAAJ&q=%22quit+while+he%27s+behind%22&dq=%22quit+while+he%27s+behind%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjy77S_3pjdAhXlhFQKHeLNDUwQ6AEIPzAF) (1968), quoting a column by James Reston in the *New York Times* that was reprinted in the *Columbus [Ohio] Citizen-Journal* on November 8, 1968 [combined snippets]:

> "The trouble with Hubert Humphrey is that he probably won't **quit while he's behind** [after losing to Richard Nixon in the 1968 presidential election], or enjoy the pleasures of defeat, He will rest for a few weeks and then get back in the political battle, ...

The expression also appears in David Profumo, [*The Weather in Iceland*](https://books.google.com/books?id=7DVbAAAAMAAJ&q=%22quit+while+you%27re+behind%22&dq=%22quit+while+you%27re+behind%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwix-ra50JjdAhWnhlQKHZCdBx84ChDoAQgoMAA) (1993) [combined snippets]:

> Kit said he was getting bored with the low strike-rate, so we decided to roll the fishing grounds for just two more days before packing it in. This is usually a mistake (it's better to **quit while you're behind**, than compound your failures), but for once we had a real run of luck, and managed a double-header.

And from David Berg, [*The Trial Lawyer: What It Takes to Win*](https://books.google.com/books?id=zhEPN-B9VhkC&pg=PA249&dq=%22quit+while+you%27re+behind%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiN05ii0JjdAhUSDHwKHWUxBmMQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22quit%20while%20you%27re%20behind%22&f=false) (2006):

> On the other hand, if your witness cratered on the stand—was so bad it's doubtful redirect can help her—**quit while you're behind**. Ask a few questions if you have to, but add nothing new to stir up significant recross.

The other relevant idiomatic phrase, which has much the same sense as "quit while you're behind," is **cut [one's] losses**. Jeffrey Moore, [*Prisoner in a Red-Rose Chain*](https://books.google.com/books?id=zixgjWMAZ9kC&q=%22quit+while+I%27m+behind%22+%22cut+my+losses%22&dq=%22quit+while+I%27m+behind%22+%22cut+my+losses%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZp_Ks3ZjdAhUCK3wKHZbTDgQQ6AEIKTAA) (1999) uses both expressions in the same sentence:

> Milena was looking me in he eye. I looked away, towards my mood ring: black. Should I **cut my losses**, **quit while I'm behind**, admit I haven't the faintest idea of what I'm talking about?

Answer (score 3):

As per your example scenario, the following idiom may help.

> Stop, you are ***shooting yourself in the foot***.

TFD(idioms):

> **[shoot (oneself) in the foot](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/shoot+in+the+foot)**
>   To do or say something that inadvertently undermines one's interests.
>
> American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition.
>
> Copyright © 2016 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company.
>   Published by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights
>   reserved.

Answer (score 0):

A variant of [***you're your own worst enemy***](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/own+worst+enemy) can be bent to fill almost any sentence structure, such as *Person 2 says, "You're being your own worst enemy"*.

> If you say that someone is their own worst enemy, you mean that their own behaviour causes most of their problems.

TFD

Answer (score -1):

Phrasal Verb:  **to piss on** or **to piss all over**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/144598?rskey=8hkzc8&result=1#eid30390318)

> To show great contempt or scorn towards; to humiliate

As in your example:

Person 2 tells them "Stop, you're just ****pissing all over** yourself!"